# Convert decimal to a mathematical multiple fractions of 1/4 in Python

Tags: python, fractions

I want to compute a cup size based on a weight.
One cup is defined as 240gr weight.
I need to get the number of cups of a weight `x` in gr (decimal number), in the mathematical multiple fraction of `1/4`.
Result should be a string.

So, possible values should be limited to:
0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1 1/4, 1 1/2, 1 3/4, 2 and so on.

Examples:

```
x = 130.3
```

cup_size: 1/2

```
x = 10
```

cup_size: 0

```
x = 310
```

cup_size: 1 1/4

How can I implement this in python?
I was reading the [Fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module but I can't find something as I need.

As requested by Nathaniel, I'm not sure how to solve this math thing in python. I think it could exists a method in a library to do that. That's why I'm asking here.

So far, what I've tried is to convert with `as_integer_ratio` method:

```
weight = 351
unit = 240
weight_to_convert = int(round(weight/unit))
print(weight_to_convert.as_integer_ratio())
```

But this is not working, is just giving me the value as the nearest integer fraction.

Comment: Do you want the output as strings, or actual Fraction objects? You shouldn't be using floating point objects as those have rounding errors

Comment: The output should be a string

Comment: Start with `round(amount / 240, 3)`. Then write a function to round to the nearest quarter cup

Comment: @NathanielFord I don't know how to solve this thing. I added what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might nudge you in the right direction:

```
def cups(val):
    full, quarter = divmod(val // 60, 4)
    if not (full or quarter):
        return "0"
    f = f"{full:.0f}" if full else ""
    if quarter:
        if quarter == 2:
            f += " 1/2"
        else:
            f += f" {quarter:.0f}/4" 
    return f.strip()

>>> cups(130)
'1/2'
>>> cups(310)
'1 1/4'
>>> cups(10)
'0'
```

Some docs:

- [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)
- [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Comment: This is the exact solution of the question. The magic is on divmod method.
Thanks user2390182!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The core of this problem is that you're trying to 'bucket' a variable number of grams into some number of quarter cups, keeping discrete units and avoiding floats.

Going straight to the heart of this problem, rather than trying to determine what to do with the fractional remainder of any division, you should just ask how many quarter cups are in any given amount:

```
quarters = val / (240 / 4)  # Alternatively, (val * 4) / 240) or val / 60
```

Now it's a matter of determining the remainder per four.

```
cups = quarters // 4
quotient = quarters % 4
```

The above gets the cups and quarter cups. Now we print:

```
if quotient == 0:  # Here there is no fraction
    f"cup_size = {cups}"
elif quotient == 2:  # In this case we need to reduce the fraction
    "cup_size = {} {} / 2".format(cups, quotient / 2)
else:
    f"cup_size = {cups} {quotient} / 4"
```

If you need to handle the fractions more abstractly, using a fraction class would make sense - but the trick of multiplying by your divisor (in this case four because a quarter cup is your smallest unit) gets you your value in non-float terms. You can drop the remainder.